# Fast query slows down when within a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT timestmp
    FROM devicelog 
    WHERE device_id = 5
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

which takes less than 0.001 seconds to fetch, but once I put it in a subquery, it slows down to about 3.05 seconds. Any reason to why it does this, or how I can remedy it?

Here is the second query (which is the one I want to optimize):

```
SELECT device.id,
    (SELECT timestmp
    FROM devicelog 
    WHERE device_id = device.id
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as timestmp
FROM device
```

Table "device" only has like 10-15 records in it (devicelog has several million), so I would assume it goes 1 by 1 through each record and then executes the subquery, but obviously it's doing something else. The PK of devicelog is the id, and the PK in device is its id as well. There is an index on devicelog for `timestmp` (which is a datetime) and `device_id` which is also a FK back to devicelog. There are other indices as well, but they are irrelevant (things like names, descriptions, etc).

I just need it to loop through devices, then display the last timestamp record.

If I list each device in PHP, then perform the first query separately, it will be perform extraordinary well, but I want to do this in one entire query. Like, I could do something like (pseudocode):

```
foreach($row in <devicelog>)
   query('<first query> where id = $row[id]')
```

Doing an entire join would be too expensive on devicelog just because the high count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and query do not match what you are looking for per the comment to the first answer offered.

What you can do is a pre-aggregate on a per-device basis to get the max ID log, then join that to your master list of devices...

```
SELECT 
      d.name,
      d.id,
      DeviceMax.lastTime
   from
      device d
         LEFT JOIN ( select dl.device_id,
                            max( dl.timestamp ) lastTime
                        from
                           devicelog dl
                        group by
                           dl.device_id ) as DeviceMax
            ON d.id = DeviceMax.device_id
```

Now, if you needed other stuff from the device log for that specific entry, we could just add on to that...

```
LEFT JOIN devicelog dl2
   on DeviceMax.Device_id = dl2.Device_id
   AND DeviceMax.lastTime = dl2.timestamp
```

then you can get any other columns from the "dl2" alias added to your query.

Also, for your device log table, I would have a covering index on (device_id, timestamp)

**COMMENT FROM FEEDBACK**

Then I would offer this as a suggestion for you, which is something also common in the world of web development when someone needs "highest count", or "most" of something, or "most recent" etc.

Denormalize your Device table with only one respect... add a column for the LastDeviceLogID.  Then, whenever your DeviceLog has an entry added to it, you just use an after insert trigger that does...

```
update Device 
   set LastDeviceLogID = newRecord.DeviceLogID
   where ID = newRecord.Device_ID
```

Columns may not be exact, but the principle is there.  This way, you never need to do a LIMIT 1, MAX(), etc and go through your millions of records, you can get as simply as doing

```
SELECT 
      d.name,
      d.id,
      dl.timestamp,
      dl.othercolumns
   from
      device d
         LEFT JOIN devicelog dl
            on d.LastDeviceLogID = dl.DeviceLogID
```

Comment: Tried it and it takes around 7 seconds. There are several indices on device_id (PK) and timestamp.

Comment: @RalphWiggum, revised answer for denormalization technique

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking an insert trigger would be the best way to do it, but was trying to avoid using one.

Answer (score 1):

try this with inner join

```
  SELECT d.id, dl.timestamp
  FROM device d
  INNER JOIN  devicelog  dl
  ON  dl.device_id = d.id
  ORDER BY d.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

to list all devices you may consider the GROUP BY

```
  SELECT d.id, dl.timestamp
  FROM device d
  INNER JOIN  devicelog  dl
  ON  dl.device_id = d.id
  GROUP BY d.id
  ORDER BY d.id DESC
```

Edit:

if you have many indices , thn better to index your column id

try this

```
  ALTER TABLE `device` ADD INDEX `id` (`id`)
```

Comment: This is fine for just one row in device, but I need to list all the devices along with the last devicelog record.

Comment: Still only returns 1 row because of the `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Took about 6.5 seconds, unfortunately.

Comment: this query is very simple. Can you show your explain tables.?

Comment: its all based on a misinterpretation of his question vs what they want per his first comment to your answer above.

Comment: @echo_Me I'll put it in the original post.